# sentry error tracking in self calling async function

Tags: node.js, express, sentry

I'm very new to sentry and I'm trying to study error tracking with sentry. Following code snipet
on purpose I'm set a invalid mongodb uri and tried to catch the error with sentry. But Sentry.cptureException not sending the error message. But if I set a correct mongo uri and test with the debug route it's catching and sending error to dashboard. What I'm doing wrong?

```
Sentry.init({ dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DSN });

(async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {

    const app = express();
    app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler() as express.RequestHandler);

    await mongodb.connectAsync(process.env.MONGO_DEV_DB as string);

    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/api', cors: false });

    app.get('/debug', () => {
      throw new Error('My first Sentry error!');
    });

    app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler() as express.ErrorRequestHandler);

    app.listen(PORT, () => debug(` App is Listening on port ${PORT}`));
  } catch (err) {
    Sentry.captureException(err);
    console.error(err);
    await mongodb.closeAsync();
    process.exit(1);
  }
})();
```

Comment: It doesn't have a chance to send it before shutdown. Likely this, https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/2049

Comment: so it means captureException dont have asyn support??